# i need help with device driver

Tags: drivers

i am new on linux, really don't know any thing about it

i have a HDMI Encoder work on linux centos 7 OS, the motherboard is down and dont boot, i replace another motherboard with other processor, because the first ones is 6th Gen and i buy new 10 Gen board and cpu

when i install my encoder and boot up i see error pci on my program, when i search online i found some commands to see devices with drivers,

02:00.0 Unassigned class FF00 : Altera Corp Device 1172:0008 Rev 01

how i install driver or enable pci or how i get first driver and update again, don't know where i start, its same hard drive and os, just change motherboard and cpu

any suggestion pls

Comment: Altera is a manufacturer of FPGA chips, which can be programmed for any purpose. It looks like your HDMI encoder would need a FPGA firmware download to appear as anything other than a generic FPGA chip. Presumably the software associated with the HDMI encoder would handle that. But from that output, it's not really possible to know the make and model of your HDMI encoder, which would be important here.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i have other device is working good, is that help in any way, and about the hard drive is still have all files and data before the motherboard issue

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HDMI encoder's *manufacturer* and *model name/number* to it, so that people reading the question can know which device you are talking about, and can look up further information on it.